# What is the class of shapes with maximum area for a given volume and surface curvature?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, 3d, area, volume

If we consider a sphere with volume *V* and radius *R*, its surface area is minimal among all shapes of volume *V*. The radius of curvature of the surface is *R* at all points.

What shapes will we obtain if we try to **maximize** its surface area while keeping *V* constant and allowing the radius of curvature of its surface to be less than *R*, but no less than *kR, 0 < k < 1*?

Intuitively, it seems that for some range of *k*, the shape should look like an erythrocyte (a red blood cell). What else can be said about those shapes? 
At what value of *k* the optimal shape becomes non-convex? Non-simply-connected? What happens when k → 0? What happens when we restrict the shapes to simply-connected?

(The radius of curvature of a surface at a point is the minimum of all radii of curvature of the intersections of the surface and normal planes at the point.)